# File is immediately deleted after using cat

Tags: linux, debian, shell

I'm currently facing an extremely strange issue I'm not sure where to begin to diagnose. I have a directory of log files written using `winston` (and its daily rotate transport). When I go in that directory and use `ls` to view the directory contents, I do not see the logfile of today in there. However, when I use `cat` to output its contents, it is in fact there and the contents are printed. When I try to use `cat` a second time (exact same command), the file seems to have been deleted.

```
user@host:/media/s3/logs$ ls
[...list of files, but the file below is NOT included...]
user@host:/media/s3/logs$ cat error-host-2023-11-21.log
[...contents of file...]
user@host:/media/s3/logs$ cat error-host-2023-11-21.log
cat: error-host-2023-11-21.log: No such file or directory
```

I have no idea what's happening. Could anyone give me a direction where to look?

Comment: `s3` sounds like that could be a network filesystem with funny consistency guarantees. You should [edit] your question to clarify what mount/filesytem you are dealing with.

Comment: Questions seeking installation, configuration or diagnostic help must include the desired end state, the specific problem or error, sufficient information about the configuration and environment to reproduce it, and attempted solutions. As also include the Research that has been done. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers and are unlikely to get good answers.

Comment: Perhaps someone has aliased or created a cat function which will rm the file after.